# Get a max date column using where clause in Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a pivot table that is intermediate between `users` and `subscriptions`. Here is the schema:

```
 Schema::create('users_subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('subscription_code_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->timestamp('expired_at')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('subscription_code_id')->references('id')->on('subscription_codes')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

So the relation is many-to-many, and I need to look for this pivot table to get the expired subscripsion users. Here is my query builder:

```
$query->select(self::columns())
                  ->join('users_subscriptions', 'users.id', '=', 'users_subscriptions.user_id')
                  ->where('users_subscriptions.expired_at', '<=', now())
                  ->groupBy('users.id')
                  ->orderBy('users_subscriptions.expired_at', 'asc')
```

Sample data of the pivot table `users_subscritions`:

| user_id | subscription_code_id | created_at | updated_at | expired_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 69440 | 2021-01-23 20:55:37 | 2021-01-23 20:55:37 | 2019-01-23 20:55:37 |
| 1 | 69441 | 2021-01-23 21:01:14 | 2021-01-23 21:01:14 | 2023-01-23 20:55:37 |

The issue is that the query looking for the **first record** in the pivot table and check against it. **I need to look for the max `expired_at` and check against only.**
The expected result is to check for the second row in the pivot table because it has the max `expired_at` value. Therefore, the `user_id` 1 has a valid subscription.

I think I need to use subquery but not sure how to accomplish this.

Thank you

Comment: [Update your question please](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66716811/edit) .. include a sample data from those pivot table. Also, I personally don't use `laravel` so I can't make out what's the plain MySQL query from that query builder. Can you post the plain MySQL query version? Thanks

Comment: I've included sample data. The query is generate a simple MySQL join. Can you suggest a MySQL query for the case? Thanks @FaNo_FN

Comment: One more thing, show us what would be your expected result from your sample data above.

Comment: I've added the expected result. @FaNo_FN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will return what you want:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(expired_at) AS ed
FROM users_subscriptions
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING ed > NOW();
```

I'm not sure how to write it in query builder format though. What I did there is returning the `MAX(expired_at)` for each `id` then group it bt `id`. I notice that your query builder have `users_subscriptions` join with `users` but judging from the create table statement, running this query on `users_subscriptions` is enough to get the expired date value and I'm guessing that the join with `users` is just there to return user additional info. The next operation after `GROUP BY` is `HAVING` - this is to filter out `expired_at`. Note that since I assign `MAX(expired_at)` with alias `ed`, I reuse the same alias in `HAVING`. However, I'm not sure the behaviour of query builder whether this is acceptable or not but if it's not, you can change to:

```
HAVING MAX(expired_at) > NOW()
```

P/S: Whether its `>`, `>=`, `<=` or `<`, I'll let you decide that .. because I see you're using `<=` in your query builder.

Here's a fiddle for reference: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b95ebc606916e60dc0ed25777c0390a7

Comment: Thanks it's working by using `having` instead of `where`